# OWL to JSON converter

Tags: json, taxonomy, owl, ontology

I need to convert this OWL ontology file to JSON in order to integrate it in an HTML5 webpage for visualisation:

[this is the OWL ontology file in question](https://kask.eti.pg.gda.pl/redmine/projects/ocs/repository/revisions/55/annotate/devel/examples/security_secure_business_austria/securityontology.owl)

Answer (score 2):

I use the tool of WebVOWL, http://vowl.visualdataweb.org/webvowl/owl2vowl_0.1.4.zip which works quite well.

the command is `java -jar owl2vowl.jar -file yourfile.owl`

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

OWL API version 4.0.1 can save in two JSON variants: `RDFJsonDocumentFormat` and `RDFJsonLDDocumentFormat`.

Either one might do what you're looking for. In order to use them, they need to be specified as arguments to `OWLOntologyManager::save()`.

Examples for this are available https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/wiki/Documentation

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of the method Ignazio mentioned:

```
OWLOntologyManager m = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
    OWLOntology o = m.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(new File("my/path/file.owl"));
    StringDocumentTarget target = new StringDocumentTarget();

    org.semanticweb.owlapi.formats.RDFJsonDocumentFormat documentFormat = new RDFJsonDocumentFormat();
    m.saveOntology(o, documentFormat, target);

    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(new File("thesaurus.json"));
    writer.write(target.toString());
    writer.close();
```